# github pull request builder workflow with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I am completely new to DevOps and couldn't fix the builder and merger plugin flow.

I have 2 Jenkins jobs.
job A: pipeline with build trigger as GitHub Pull Request Builder.
job B: freestyle project which is triggered on the successful completion of job A (uploading artifacts to Nexus etc.)

Job A should be triggered automatically once pull request is created in GitHub but it doesn't work at all. Below is from GitHub.
[GitHub says "CI setup hasn't been done yet"][1]

***Continuous integration has not been set up***

Even if i build Job A manually, Job B doesn't merge.

Not sure what to look into.

Comment: Please show your work -- what have you done to try and solve the problem so far, and what errors have you gotten? Please see documentation on writing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you asked a more direct question re: what you're trying to accomplish. -m

Comment: Basically I am trying to invoke/trigger Jenkins CI job when a pull request is created to the corresponding repo. Below are the build triggers which I have mentioned..  it is pipeline job.                                                                                                              General -> Project URL is provided after checking Git project.                                      Build triggers -> Selected 'GitHub Pull Request Builder'. API credentials are given, admin-list is updated, selected Use 'github hooks for build triggering'. Pipeline is there in GitHub as Jenkinsfile,